# Как решить проблему, вылетает ошибка "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" работая через putty по ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh, arm, lxc

Есть docker ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.8 armv71). 
Когда подключился через putty к ssh серверу, проходит секунд 10-15 и появляется ошибка

> "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрю на сервере командой `sudo ssh status`, ssh не рабочий(:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Помогает команда `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`**

После этой команды, вроде все норм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если докер перегрузить, сервер работает, но после первого подключения по ssh все повторяется:-(

Вывод команды **`#journalctl -u ssh`**, и ее последний результат:

> Dec 29 15:32:46 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   **Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
>
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Failed with result 'signal'.**
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 sshd[454]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 sshd[454]: Server listening on :: port 2222.
>   Dec 29 15:33:17 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   **Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
>
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Failed with result 'signal'.**
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 sshd[456]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 sshd[456]: Server listening on :: port 2222.
>   Dec 29 15:33:49 ubuntu-bionic-armhf-1 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASd74.png): Started OpenBSD Secure Shell serv

Пытался прописать строчки в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` на сервере:

```
 - TCPKeepAlive yes | ClientAliveInterval 60 | ClientAliveCountMax 360
```

не помогает....

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы sshd не падал и стабильно работал. Спасибо!

Comment: Какой у Вас стоит GraceTime в config? Так же в файле sshd.service попробуйте прописать RestartSec в секции [Service]

Comment: не могу найти где лежит этот файл( по пути /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service его нет.... делал комманду find . -sshd.service, файл не найден. В конфиге GraceTime  не указан ни где.

Comment: Он должен находится в systemd. Посмотрите в /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service

Comment: Нашел конф. файл -sshd.service! Спасибо! для ключа RestartSec (его нет в данном файле)  какое значение не обходимо поставить? Еще пробовал KillMode в этой же секции на mixed поставить вместо process - не помогает.. (

Comment: в RestartSec проставляйте количество секунд. К примеру 60.  Так же можете проставить Restart=on-failure.

Comment: Не забудьте перезапустить демон.

Comment: Вроде помогло, то что прописал Restart=always . Сейчас поставил на тест. Если минут через 30 не отвалиться, напишите решение как ответ, и я его приму, балы лишними не бывают) Спасибо большое, за помощь! Я сюда отпишусь, через 30 мин по результату!)

Comment: По ходу работает, не отваливается! Denis640Kb, спасибо Вам за помощь! Напишите ответ про Restart=always. Приму. Спасибо за указанное направление!

Comment: Рад был помочь )

Answer (score 0):

В файле `sshd.service` попробуйте прописать `RestartSec` в секции `[Service]`

```
Restart=always
```

Файл находится в  `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`